# How to show Json field value in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a json field in my database name is **permissions** `{"read": true, "create": true}`. Now, I want to show this in my **blade** view. I had try this way but it's show an error.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
      <tr>

    <td>{{$user->roles->permissions}}</td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

show this Error Message.
`Property [permissions] does not exist on this collection instance.`

User Model

```
 public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'user_roles');
}
```

Comment: try it : {{$user->roles['permissions']}}

Comment: is `permissions`field in `roels` table ?

Comment: yes, **permissions** field is in **roles** table.

Comment: I have tried `{{$user->roles['permissions']}}`, it's show **Undefined Index** error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this scenario and was OK . i hope usefull for you :

my `route` :

```
Route::get('/test', function (Request $request) {

    $users=\App\User::with('roles')->get();
    return view('welcome',compact('users'));
});
```

define `roles` method inside `user` model :

```
 public function roles()
 {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'user_roles');;
 }
```

and get `permissions` in `view` :

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @foreach($user->roles as $role)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$role}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforea
@endforeach
```

I test with these tables

`user_roles`

```
user_id | role_id 
-----------------
 1 | 2         
 1 | 2
```

`roles`:

```
id | permissions 
-----------------
 1 | {"read": true, "create": true}        
 2 | {"read": true, "create": false}
```

`users`:

```
id | name | email | password | remember_token | created_at|updated_at 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | alihossein|ali@gmail.com|XXXXX|UIWKK67ei5CCuiv1OXilKY2aRkTfSqGLpqJch0F9YmenGSorsQGHVvWiX6kP| 2018-05-28 22:25:14 | 2018-05-28 22:25:14
```

Comment: Can a user have a lot of `role` in `user_roles` table ?

Comment: I do not know exactly what the you database `schema` is. I check the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172318/discussion-between-alihossein-shahabi-and-gabrielle).